# CKAN extension development requirements

Tags: ckan

Do I have to install CKAN from source and not from package in order to create new extensions? My current installation is from package and it seems to me that I have all the CKAN source files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to develop a CKAN extension you have to install CKAN from source.

We're working on a new tutorial for writing CKAN extensions, you can see the draft version of the tutorial here: https://github.com/okfn/ckan/pull/943

Comment: This tutorial made it in to the CKAN docs as the extending guide: <https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/index.html>. There's also a separate theming guide too: <https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/index.html>